# What current flows through a Zener diode that is in parallel with the gate of a MOSFET?

Tags: diodes, zener, pmos

I was reviewing this circuit and I can't figure out how much current goes through the Zener diode. I understand that it is there to protect the MOSFET gate against high voltages but how much current flows through while charging the C<sub>GS</sub> capacitor?

I assume that the current that charges the capacitor between gate and source (C<sub>GS</sub>) should flow through the zener diode, is that correct? But if the impedance of the Zener were as low (as it usually is) as about 5 Ω, it would load the capacitor with a huge current spike that would destroy the Zener, or am I wrong?

What current must the Zener support in this circuit?

[image]

Comment: ideally, (VCC1/R1)

Comment: "I understand that it is there to protect the MOSFET gate against high voltages" Actually the purpose of this looks like reverse polarity protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zener is used to protect the gate from over voltage. Vgs has a maximum voltage rating, often around 20V.

This is a reverse voltage protection circuit. The zener's current is limited by the gate bias resistor (R1) as explained in @datenheim's post. The LTspice simulation below shows the various waveforms when the voltage source is swept from -30 V to +30 V. Note the step in the output voltage which shows the body diode forward voltage drop when the FET isn't conducting, and jumps up when the FET is turned on. Note, the X-axis is the input voltage, V(in).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> *I assume that the current that charges the capacitor between gate and source (C<sub>GS</sub>) should flow through the Zener diode, is that correct?*

There will be negligible current through the zener as the gate-source capacitance of the MOSFET charges. The zener diode is there to prevent excessive voltage from the supply (on the left) exceeding the gate-source voltage rating for the MOSFET. So, if the input voltage gets too high the zener will conduct but, by then, the MOSFET will be fully activated so it won't matter (and it's gate is protected by the zener diode conducting).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the current will be roughly (VCC1 - V_pd - Vz(D1))/R1 in the beginning, and as soon as the FET turned on increase very little to (VCC1 - Vds - Vz(D1))/R1.

Here V_pd is the forward drop of the FET's protection diode, Vz(D1) is the zener voltage. The current Iz thus mainly depends on R1. That few nano coulomb going to the gate are negligible.